# My OS crashes randomly after I start using any application that plays audio

Tags: sound, release-odin

I recently migrated from Windows 10 to Elementary OS 6 Odin, It has god essentially everything I need for my school work, it's amazing, it's faster than Windows 10, I loved it, unless, it starts freezing randomly whenever I am doing any task that plays audio in it (eg. YouTube, Spotify, Google Meet), if I am not doing something that plays audio in it (like writing this thing), it works pretty fine.

I read some other posts saying Ctrl+Alt+F1 and killall in case everything freezes, but it doesn't work, when I try to use the Ctrl+Alt+F1, it gets nowhere. It is frozen and all I can do is do a hard reboot.

Any suggestions on how I could fix this, I really love the Linux and the Elementary OS experience, but this problem hinders it a lot.

**Notes:-**

1. I am using the proprietary drivers for everything
2. I have the latest version of the OS with all the updates installed
3. Everything else is working fine, except when I play Audio it crashes with nothing working and the only option left is to Hard Reboot

My Laptop is an Asus E200HA-FD0005TS 11.6-inch Laptop
Quad-Core Intel® Atom™ x5-Z8300  CPU @ 1.44GHz
2GB DDR3 memory (4 GB of swap is also available)
32GB of EMMC storage dedicated to Elementary OS (No other OS on boot)

**EDIT**
I ran the following commands and got these outputs:-

```
sudo lshw -c audio
```

Got no output

```
sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 22)  

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 22)

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 22)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 22)

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 22)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 22)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 22)

01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 30)
```

.

```
free -m

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1872        1228          84         389         560         108
Swap:          4095        1150        2944
```

**This is with 6 firefox tabs and a terminal window**

Comment: It’s interesting that you can run Odin on a machine with 2GB RAM and 4GB of swap on an eMMC device. The minimum recommended requirements asks for double this. That said, could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of the following commands: (1) `sudo lshw -c audio` (2) `sudo lspci` (3) `free -m`. This will show information about your hardware and system memory, making it easier to offer suggestions 

Comment: @matigo sure will do :D